# How can the job of SDFlasher.exe given with FriendlyARM utility be accomplished on Linux?

Tags: linux, embedded

I am playing with **FriendlyARM Tiny 6410**. The instructions on setting up an SD card for booting self compiled versions of linux kernel involve the use of **SDFlasher.exe**. 
People have tried to find an alternative for Linux here http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/3295 in vain.

I am sure that whatever the utility does can be accomplished using some simple commands on the terminal, provided we know what exactly it does.
Can somebody help?

The getting started instructions are available here - http://www.minidevs.com/Tiny6410/Bootloader.html#2_1_Create_the_SD_boot_card_39_45863506360910833

Comment: Closed as off topic?  I'd think that asking about tools directly related to programming would be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://code.google.com/p/mini6410-debian/downloads/detail?name=SD-Flasher.exe&can=2&q=) what you are looking for?

The thread you referenced does not say the utility was not found as you have suggested, but rather that it did not work in Wine.  It is probably performing some low-level operation on the SD card that is not supported by the Wine emulation.  You may be better off using a genuine installation of Windows either stand-alone or in a Virtual Machine.  A VM will give a much more accurate execution environment for Windows than Wine, but requires a Windows licence of course.

[This](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardBeginners#SD_card_setup) may be of some use.  It refers to creating a bootable SD card for BeagleBoard, but I think it is generally applicable (since it is also given on the Raspberry Pi Wiki)

Comment: I do have the .exe but being a Linux enthusiast I am more inclined towards finding an alternate method.